# Did not receive state packet from Tello error

Tags: python, tello-drone

I'm facing a 'Did not receive state packet from Tello' error when trying to execute the below code in anaconda environment. Can someone help on this please?

```
from djitellopy import tello
from time import sleep

me = tello.Tello()
me.connect()
print(me.get_battery())

me.takeoff()
me.send_rc_control(0,20,0,0)
sleep(2)
me.send_rc_control(0,0,0,0)
me.land()
```

Full error trace:

```
[INFO] tello.py - 122 - Tello instance was initialized. Host: '192.168.10.1'. Port: '8889'.
[INFO] tello.py - 437 - Send command: 'command'
[INFO] tello.py - 461 - Response command: 'ok'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/OpencvPython/venv/basicmovementconda.py", line 5, in <module>
    me.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\Tellotest\lib\site-packages\djitellopy\enforce_types.py", line 54, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\Tellotest\lib\site-packages\djitellopy\tello.py", line 546, in connect
    raise Exception('Did not receive a state packet from the Tello')
Exception: Did not receive a state packet from the Tello
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I'm on a 3.9 environment on Linux and I had my firewall turned on, so I turn it off and it worked!

Comment: How did you turn off firewall. I am using raspberry pi 4 and followed "https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/security/how-to-stop-and-disable-firewalld/" but still i get same error.